# close tab window browser after change page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

I want to use a button in a desktop app that will close the current browser tab.
the script works fine if I have opened that page for the first time, but isn't working I use it in a second page.

Example: I open a new tab with the homepage. Then, from there, I navigate on another page where there's the exit button. 
Here i want the people to be able to exit but they can't.
Esle, if I open directly the second page the button works fine closing the tab correctly.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<a href="javascript:closeWindow();">Close Window</a>






<script>
    function closeWindow() {
        window.open('','_parent','');
        window.close();
    }
</script>
```

anyone knows hot to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help:

```js
function closeWindow() {
    window.open('', '_blank');
    window.close();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="closeWindow()"> Close</div>
<script src="js.js"></script>
```